# PHP function to find matching url from wordpress posts

Tags: php, wordpress, url

I'm looking for php code or function which can help me to search and find first matching URL, based on specific pattern, from a wordpress post and echo the same url in the same post where it's necessary instead of modifying parent url. 
Example Case:
URL:https://example.com/education_system_comparison.html
when I open this page, afer title of the post, there is description of this post, here I want to search from description to find matching url that must starts from my desired domain name like https://some-url-is-here/3978732978937298.html and ends with .html
If anyone here can help me to create a function or use any filters those can work with wordpress or php, it would be so helping and must appreciated. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution what I was looking for and it's working perfectly fine on single post or on custom page.
Here is function, I've added in functions.php of my WordPress theme;

```
function getBetween($content,$start,$end){
$r = explode($start, $content);
if (isset($r[1])){
    $r = explode($end, $r[1]);
    return $r[0];
}
return ''; }
```

so I can call above function by using following code and it work 100% fine, example code:

```
<?php
    $content_post = get_post($my_postid);
    $content = $content_post->post_content;
    $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
    $start = ' https://some-url-is-here/';
    $end = '"';
    $output = getBetween($content,$start,$end);
    echo $start.$output; ?>
```

It gives output like below based on first matching url and stop immediately

```
https://some-url-is-here/3978732978937298.html
```

On the other hand, once I applied the same code throughout my website so I can get every matching url from each and every published post to use it where necessary on the same post. As I save changes, my server got halted coz there were hundreds of httpd requests started processing and server went down immediately. 
I'm not sure what exactly is going wrong here, If anyone can guide me and help me what exactly wrong here so it'll be much appreciated and any suggestion or fix, Thanks.